# Derivative of an absolute value function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, partial-derivative

Let $f$ is a real function. This derivation is true or not?
\begin{equation}
|f^{\prime}(t)|^{m}.f^{\prime \prime\prime}(t).f^{\prime\prime}(t)\\
=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt} [|f^{\prime}(t)|^{m}.|f^{\prime\prime}(t)|^{2}]-\dfrac{m}{2} |f^{\prime}(t)|^{m-1}.|f^{\prime\prime}(t)|^{3}
\end{equation}
where $m$ is an integer and $f^{\prime}(t)=\dfrac{d}{dt}f(t)$

Comment: yes is my fault. thank you.

Comment: yes there is an error I corrected it.

Comment: Things would be more readable if you replaced everywere $f′$ by $g$, $f′′$ by $g′$, etc. And you should explain what makes you hope this is true, and why you are not sure. In fact becomes (obviously) true if you remove all your absolute values, but it is false otherwise.